# Downloading JSON data using R in Tableau

Tags: json, r, tableau-api

I want to use data from an openFDA [API](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20090601+TO+20140731]&count=effective_time), which is in JSON format, in Tableau so that when the data changes Tableau can also update the visualization when refreshed. I tried to use R code inside Tableau but I am getting an error message. The code I am using is:

```
SCRIPT_INT('library(jsonlite);
fda<-fromJSON("https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20090601+TO+20140731]&count=effective_time");
fda<-fda$results;
fda<-fda[,2]')
```

and the error message I am getting:

```
"STRING_INT is being used with(string), did you mean (string, ...)?"
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

In R, it works fine as shown below:

```
library(jsonlite)
fda<-fromJSON("https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20090601+TO+20140731]&count=effective_time")
fda<-fda$results;
fda<-fda[,2]
class(fda)
head(fda)
```

Comment: did u try already: fda <- fromJSON(file = "https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=effective_time:[20090601+TO+20140731]&count=effective_time", unexpected.escape = "keep")

Comment: @user3502164, I tried it after your suggestion but still getting the same error message.